# iOS Fastlane Gym - Extra Incorrect Provisioning Profile When Building App

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I'm in the process of setting up Fastlane so that it uses manual provisioning profiles, which i'm managing via Match. Match is set up and working fine, and i've managed to set the correct provisioning profiles correctly in XCode via XCConfig files that point to each of the required targets (one for the main app and two for notifications related targets).

However, when I build the app in Fastlane, Gym is having problems detecting the correct provisioning profile because an extra, unwanted provisioning profile is being incorrectly identified. This is the code from my [fastfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN94m.png) with placeholder bundles/provisioning profile names. You can see that I'm only specifying 3 profiles, and that I want an app-store build.

I'm receiving this [warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4zeH.png) that there are multiple profiles for bundle identifiers as part of the output.

And in the gym summary, I can see that there is an extra [unrequested provisioning profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDfCW.png) being displayed, which I've circled in blue.

The app does build successfully, in spite of the errant profile, but I'd prefer that it wasn't there at all. Where is gym pulling the errant provisioning profile from, and how do I stop it from being detected as one of the profiles for the build.

Thanks